# UISplitViewController StoryBoards segue to replace detailview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

My storyboard that has the `UISplitViewController` as the initial view controller.  Its master view has a `UITableView` embedded in a navigation controller, and there is a detail view controller which contains a `MKMapView`. Clicking on the table cell of the first table view segues into second table view controller.

Clicking on the cell of the second table view segues into second detail view, which is an image view. The segue type is "Replace" with the destination of "Detail Split". Basically, it loads up the image related to the row in second tableView in the detail view.

I am able to navigate back to my first tableview fine. I want to display the first detail view
when the first table view shows up. The reason being that it displays a map view which is related to the contents of the table view. I read quite a bit about it but did not figure out on how to do that. Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to your first TableViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   // existing code if you have any

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue ID for your map" sender:self];
}
```